# How to incorporate mod in rolling hash of Rabin Karp algorithm?

Tags: string, algorithm, string-matching, rabin-karp

I am trying to implement the Rabin Karp algorithm with mod. The hash function which i am using is:

```
H1= c1*a^k-1 + c2*a^k-2 +c3*a^k-3 +…+ck*a^0
```

Here cx is the ASCII value of the character. And to roll it I first drop the first term by subtracting it, then multiply by a and add the new term by multiplying it with a^0.

Now the problem is to deal with large values i have used mod operations but doing that i am not able to roll it correctly. My code is as follows:

```
public class RabinKarp {
private static final int base = 26;
private static final int mod = 1180637;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String text = "ATCAAGTTACCAATA";
    String pattern = "ATA";
    char[] textArr = text.toCharArray();
    char[] patternArr = pattern.toCharArray();
    System.out.println(getMatchingIndex(textArr, patternArr));
}

public static int getMatchingIndex(char[] textArr, char[] patternArr) {
    int n = textArr.length;
    int m = patternArr.length;
    int patternHash = getHashForPatternSize(patternArr, m);
    int textHash = getHashForPatternSize(textArr, m);
    for(int i = 0; i < n-m; i++) {
        if(patternHash == textHash && checkMatch(textArr, patternArr, i, m))
            return i;
        textHash = rollingHash(textArr, textHash, i, m);    
    }
    return -1;
}

public static boolean checkMatch(char[] textArr, char[] patternArr, int i, int m) {
    for(int j = 0; j < m; j++,i++) {
        if(textArr[i] != patternArr[j])
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}

public static int rollingHash(char[] textArr, int textHash, int i, int m) {
    return (textHash * base - modularExponentiation(base, m, mod) * (int)textArr[i] + (int) textArr[i+m])%mod;
}

public static int getHashForPatternSize(char[] arr, int m) {
    int hash = 0;
    for(int i = 0, p = m; i < m; i++, p--) {
        hash = (hash%mod + calcHash(arr[i], p)%mod)%mod;
    }
    return hash;
}

public static int calcHash(char alphabet, int p) {
    return (((int) alphabet)%mod * modularExponentiation(base, p, mod)%mod)%mod;
}

public static int modularExponentiation(int base, int p, int mod) {
    if(p == 0)
        return 1;
    if(p%2 == 0)
        return modularExponentiation((base*base)%mod, p/2, mod);
    else
        return (base*modularExponentiation((base*base)%mod, (p-1)/2, mod))%mod;
}
}
```

Problem is that `textHash` and `patternHash` do not match at any point. I am sure that the problem is with the mod operations. Can anyone tell how to have mod as well as to use the rolling hash correctly. I would be very thankful.

Comment: You might need to debug the method `modularExponentation`, but I think you don't need to do it recursively. You could do it iteratively to make it less complicated.

Comment: the method is correct but the problem is the exponentiation has a sure effect and when i am trying to roll it (textHash - calcHash(textArr[i], 0))/base - this division by base is not working i think.....my target is to make this algorithm good for bigger values. I can surely choose the base as 10 and choose not to use mod but that doesnt serve my purpose

Comment: I don't know what language you're using but in most C-like languages the `%` operator does not correctly compute mod unless both operands are positive.

Comment: No problem it is all sorted now @rici

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual way to compute a Rabin-Karp rolling hash is to consider the characters in big-endian order, rather than your little-endian solution. This makes the arithmetic much easier since it avoids division. Modular division is non-trivial and you cannot simply implement it as `(p/q)%b`.

If we take the rolling hash as

```
H0…k-1 = (c0*ak-1 + c1*ak-2 + c2*ak-3 …+… ck-1*a0) mod b
```

Then the next term is:

```
H1…k   = (         c1*ak-1 + c2*ak-2 …+… ck-1*a1 + ck*a0) mod b
```

And we can easily see that

```
H1…k   = (a * H0…k-1 - c0*ak + ck) mod b
```

If we then precompute `m == ak mod b`, that becomes:

```
H1…k   = (a * H0…k-1 - m * c0 + ck) mod b
```

which is much less work on each iteration, and does not depend on division at all.

Comment: At first i implemented the big-endian solution. Failed in that then i went with the little-endian one. I would try to do yours carefully

Comment: I did try with your equations and it failed again. I will update the code in the question but to be honest your equations are just a different way to represent the same thing.

Comment: @JotWaraich: No, they're not. Division doesn't work that way with modular arithmetic.

Comment: Sure got your point but now i have updated the code as you said and i have made the solution big-endian as you said but it is still not working.

Comment: To all my discomfort i want to tell that all i implemented was correct but i had a typo. loop should run till n-m included : Instead of for(int i = 0; i < n-m; i++) it should be for(int i = 0; i <= n-m; i++) and then it runs perfectly. Thanks @rici however to point out the mistake regarding small endian and big endian. It is just frustrating that small mistakes like these sometime ruin it.

Comment: could you explain why "H1…k   = (a * H0…k-1 - c0*ak + ck) mod b" works? H1..k-1 has a mod operation at the end, why there is no mod for c0*ak + ck

Comment: @user2628641: because the modulo operator is idempotent and distributes over addition and multiplication. The first means that `(x mod b) mod b` is exactly the same as `x mod b`, and with the second means that when you are adding and multiplying, you can apply an extra `mod` if you want to, which you will typically do to avoid integer overflow.

Comment: "modulo operator is idempotent", that's the part I am missing! thank you!

Comment: @rici Does this hold as well? "(a * b) mod c = ((a mod c) * b) mod c"

Comment: @Backrub32: yes

Comment: @rici Thanks! if that's the case, is it okay to put mod operator on every term of the formula? I am confused the reason why people don't use (ck mod b) instead of (ck) from the formula you have answered. If every term can be get smaller using mod, is there a reason why I should not use it on every term from the above formula (from your answer)?

Comment: @backrub2: the only reason to avoid use of `mod` is its computational cost. If you can avoid overflow of intermediate results, for example by using a wider integer type, that's likely to be more efficient. And you certainly wouldn't bother with an`ck mod b` if you knew that `b` was greater than any possible `ck`.