# How to properly use Modulo in Rabin Karp algorithm?

Tags: python, hash, modulo, rabin-karp

I am trying to solve leetcode problem [187. Repeated DNA Sequences](https://leetcode.com/problems/repeated-dna-sequences/description/) using Rabin Karp algorithm with rolling hash approach. At first, I solved the problem without using any MOD operations like below.

```
class Solution:
    def calculate_hash(self, prime, text):
        hash_value = 0
        for i in range(len(text)):
            hash_value = hash_value + (ord(text[i]) * pow(prime, i))

        return hash_value

    def recalculate_hash(self, prime, old_hash, text, index, L):
        new_hash = old_hash - ord(text[index - 1])
        new_hash /= prime
        new_hash = new_hash + (ord(text[index + L - 1]) * pow(prime, L - 1))

        return new_hash 


    def findRepeatedDnaSequences(self, s: str) -> List[str]:
        L, s_len = 10, len(s)
        if s_len <= L:
            return []

        prime = 7
        seen, res = set(), set()
        
        old_hash = self.calculate_hash(prime, s[0:L])
        seen.add(old_hash)

        for i in range(1, s_len - L + 1):
            new_hash = self.recalculate_hash(prime, old_hash, s, i, L)
            if new_hash in seen:
                res.add(s[i:i+L])
            seen.add(new_hash)
            old_hash = new_hash    


        return list(res)
```

In the above approach, I used the little endian approach and I had to use division during the calculation of the rolling hash value. However, I came across to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50822610/4299527) in StackOverlow, where the big endian approach is suggested like below.

[image]

I tried to apply the approach but not getting desired answer. This is my tried code.

```
class Solution:
    def calculate_hash(self, prime, text, L, MOD):
        hash_value = 0 
        for i in range(len(text)):
            p_power = pow(prime, L - i - 1, MOD)
            hash_value = (hash_value + (ord(text[i]) * p_power)) % MOD

        return hash_value

    def recalculate_hash(self, prime, old_hash, text, index, L, MOD):
        p_power = pow(prime, L - 1, MOD)
        new_hash = (old_hash * prime)
        new_hash = (new_hash - (ord(text[index - 1]) * p_power) + ord(text[index + L - 1])) % MOD

        return new_hash 


    def findRepeatedDnaSequences(self, s: str) -> List[str]:
        L, s_len = 10, len(s)
        if s_len <= L:
            return []

        prime = 7
        MOD = 2**31 - 1
        seen, res = set(), set()
        
        old_hash = self.calculate_hash(prime, s[0:L], L, MOD)
        seen.add(old_hash)

        for i in range(1, s_len - L + 1):
            new_hash = self.recalculate_hash(prime, old_hash, s, i, L, MOD)
            if new_hash in seen:
                res.add(s[i:i+L])
            seen.add(new_hash)
            old_hash = new_hash    


        return list(res)
```

**What am I missing here during the MOD calculation?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def recalculate_hash(self, prime, old_hash, text, index, L, MOD):
    p_power = pow(prime, L - 1, MOD)
    new_hash = (old_hash * prime)
    new_hash = (new_hash - (ord(text[index - 1]) * p_power) + ord(text[index + L - 1])) % MOD

    return new_hash
```

The power that `ord(text[index - 1])` has when you need to subtract it is actually `L`, since the line before has already "moved it up" by one. `pow(prime, L - 1, MOD)` should therefore be `pow(prime, L, MOD)` - or alternatively, you can keep `pow(prime, L - 1, MOD)` but subtract `ord(text[index - 1]) * p_power` *before* multiplying by the `prime`.

By the way in `calculate_hash`, you don't need to calculate the power from scratch every time, you can iteratively multiply by `prime` in every iteration the same as in `recalculate_hash`.